# Border-cellspacing not working properly html

Tags: html, html-table, border-spacing

I'm having this html code:

```
<table style='border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px;'>
     <tr class='signatureContainer'>
          <td class='signatureBox' style='float: left;' >
                <span>%%%employee%%%</span>
                <hr style='margin-top: 70px;' />
                <span>%%%Role%%%</span>
          </td>
          <td class='commentsBox' style='float: left'>
                <span> &nbsp; </span>
                <hr style='margin-top: 70px;' />
                <span>Comments</span>
          </td>
          <td class='signatureBox' style='float: left'>
                <span> &nbsp; </span>
                <hr style='margin-top: 70px;' />
                <span> Master &nbsp; </span>
          </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And the following styles applied to it:

```
.signatureContainer {
display: table;
width: 100%;
margin: 30px 0 50px 0;
}
.signatureBox{
border-radius: 5px;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
min-width: 150px;
min-height: 65px;
padding: 3px;
display: block;
margin-left: 20px;'
}
.commentsBox{
border-radius: 5px;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
min-width: 600px;
min-height: 65px;
padding: 3px;
display: block;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px'
}
```

When I run the page , there is no space between the cells. Viewing the code what do you think is the problem sa that it don't looks separated.

Comment: You have extra ' after margin-left in .signatureBox class. Remove that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table style='border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px !important;'>
     <tr class='signatureContainer'>
          <td class='signatureBox' style='float: left;' >
                <span>%%%employee%%%</span>
                <hr style='margin-top: 70px;' />
                <span>%%%Role%%%</span>
          </td>
          <td class='commentsBox' style='float: left'>
                <span> &nbsp; </span>
                <hr style='margin-top: 70px;' />
                <span>Comments</span>
          </td>
          <td class='signatureBox' style='float: left'>
                <span> &nbsp; </span>
                <hr style='margin-top: 70px;' />
                <span> Master &nbsp; </span>
          </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Set `!important` while applying space.

Comment: Adding !important did not make any difference. and we should avoid !important as much as we can.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error is your css change it.

```css
.signatureContainer {
display: table;
width: 100%;
margin: 30px 0 50px 0;
}
.signatureBox{
border-radius: 5px;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
min-width: 150px;
min-height: 65px;
padding: 3px;
display: block;
margin-left: 20px;
}
.commentsBox{
border-radius: 5px;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
min-width: 600px;
min-height: 65px;
padding: 3px;
display: block;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px
}
```

```html
<table style='border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px;'>
     <tr class='signatureContainer'>
          <td class='signatureBox' style='float: left;' >
                <span>%%%employee%%%</span>
                <hr style='margin-top: 70px;' />
                <span>%%%Role%%%</span>
          </td>
          <td class='commentsBox' style='float: left'>
                <span> &nbsp; </span>
                <hr style='margin-top: 70px;' />
                <span>Comments</span>
          </td>
          <td class='signatureBox' style='float: left'>
                <span> &nbsp; </span>
                <hr style='margin-top: 70px;' />
                <span> Master &nbsp; </span>
          </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```